# OData service can be called in Browsers but in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, windows, servlets, odata, olingo

I got a sample servlet using Olingo lib: https://odata-demoservice.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/DemoService.svc/Products. It works fine in Chrome/IE/FF or in Postman. But when I query in Excel 2016/OS Windows 10 with the steps like:

- New Query
- From Other Sources
- From OData Feed

Got the error like: "We encountered an error while trying to connect. Details: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed"

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this issue?

I'm getting the same error on my service.

Answer (score 2):

@RodolfoOliveira: yes, I resolved this issue. the reason is that when I deployed it to Cloud, the uri in metadata is still http. What I did is implement a CustomProcessor and correct the url.

More detail is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-758

just need to do the custom Processor. Do the same as the original source but change a bit about the url. Detail in here: https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata4/org/apache/olingo/server/api/processor/DefaultProcessor.html

Register it with the Handler at first, then the issue should be solved.

ODataHttpHandler handler = odata.createHandler(edm);
 handler.register(new CustomDefaultProcessor());

Hope this help.